# Questions on this Query to get the MEDIAN value on a set of values

Tags: sql, median

I am trying to understand this query below, that I found on this blog (https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/median).

I have added the questions below each statement on the query. 
Can somebody help me?

```
DECLARE @c BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Items_per_Order]) 

GO


SELECT AVG(1.0 * [total_de_itens]) AS MEDIAN FROM

(
    SELECT [total_de_itens] FROM [dbo].[Items_per_Order]

    ORDER BY [total_de_itens]


OFFSET (@c - 1) / 2 ROWS
```

This is to get the first value before the exact half of the orws, right?

```
FETCH NEXT 1 + (1 - @c % 2) ROWS ONLY
```

Can somebody explain this 1 + (1 - @c % 2) equation? I did not get the use of % there as well.

What should be the equation for an odd number of rows?

) AS x

**What is purpose of this "AS x" ?**

GO

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to use `percentile_cont()` or `percentile_disc()`:

```
select top (1) percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by x) over ()
from (values (1), (1), (2), (3), (4)) v(x)
```

Comment: Yes, the thing is that this query that I am using is far more efficient to get the median (as the link above explains) but it is not well explained there.